# gather the oldest tweets and record the real time of posting

Tags: python, twitter, hashtag

how can I gather unlimited oldest tweets of many hashtags by python? (more than 20 hashtags) and assign the real date of posting tweets?

I tried the below code, but the results were the newest tweets and the posting date is not correct (record the current time of saving the tweets!)

```
import datetime
import json
import time
import tweepy
    from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
    from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
    topic_path = publisher.topic_path(" ", " ")
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("consumer_key", "consumer_secret")
    auth.set_access_token("access_token", "access_token_secret")
    api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=False)
    lst_hashtags = ["", "", "", "", "#Funny", "#Deeplearning"]
    def write_to_pubsub(data):
        try:
            if data["lang"] == "en":
                publisher.publish(topic_path, data=json.dumps({
                    "id_str": data["id_str"],
                    "id": data["id"],
                    "retweeted_id": data["retweeted_id"],
                    "favorite_count": data["favorite_count"],
                    "retweet_count": data["retweet_count"],
                    "coordinates_latitude": data["coordinates_latitude"],
                    "coordinates_longitude": data["coordinates_longitude"],
                    "place": data["place"],
                    "user_id": data["user_id"],
                    "user_name": data["user_name"],
                    "user_location": data["user_location"],
                    "user_url": data["user_url"],
                    "user_description": data["user_description"],
                    "text": data["text"],
                    "posted_at": datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data["created_at"]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                }).encode("utf-8"), tweet_id=str(data["id"]).encode("utf-8"))
        except Exception as e:
            raise
        def reformat_tweet(tweet):
        x = tweet
        processed_doc = {
            "id_str":x["id_str"],
            "id": x["id"],
            "lang": x["lang"],
            "retweeted_id": x["retweeted_status"]["id"] if "retweeted_status" in x else None,
            "favorite_count": x["favorite_count"] if "favorite_count" in x else 0,
            "retweet_count": x["retweet_count"] if "retweet_count" in x else 0,
            "coordinates_latitude": x["coordinates"]["coordinates"][0] if x["coordinates"] else 0,
            "coordinates_longitude": x["coordinates"]["coordinates"][0] if x["coordinates"] else 0,
            "place": x["place"]["country_code"] if x["place"] else None,
            "user_id": x["user"]["id"],
            "user_name": x["user"]["name"],
            "user_screen_name": x["user"]["screen_name"],
            "user_location": x["user"]["location"],
            "user_url": x["user"]["url"],
            "user_description": x["user"]["description"],
            "created_at": time.mktime(time.strptime(x["created_at"], "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y"))
        }
        if x["entities"]["hashtags"]:
            processed_doc["hashtags"] = [{"text": y["text"], "startindex": y["indices"][0]} for y in
                                         x["entities"]["hashtags"]]
        else:
            processed_doc["hashtags"] = []
        if x["entities"]["user_mentions"]:
            processed_doc["usermentions"] = [{"screen_name": y["screen_name"], "startindex": y["indices"][0]} for y in
                                             x["entities"]["user_mentions"]]
        else:
            processed_doc["usermentions"] = []
        if "extended_tweet" in x:
            processed_doc["text"] = x["extended_tweet"]["full_text"]
        elif "full_text" in x:
            processed_doc["text"] = x["full_text"]
        else:
            processed_doc["text"] = x["text"]
        return processed_doc
        class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
        def __init__(self):
            super(StdOutListener, self).__init__()
            self._counter = 0
        def on_status(self, data):
            write_to_pubsub(reformat_tweet(data._json))
            self._counter += 1
            return True
```

could anybody help me, please?

**note** I use the google cloud platform and run the code by the prompt of ssh

Comment: You're creating a StreamListener, which listens for new Tweets in realtime. You're asking how to go back and find the oldest Tweets. The only way to do that would be using the Twitter full archive search API (this is a commercial API). Even then, the API does not have a way to find the first time a particular hashtag was used. I don't think you'll be able to achieve what you're trying to do here.

Comment: OK, when I subscribe (Premium API or  Enterprise API) how can I get the first tweets?.. and you suggest exchanging "StreamListener" to what?

Comment: As I mentioned, even if you did use one of the commercial APIs, there's no actual method for finding the first use of a hashtag - you would have to search for your hashtag in stages, going backwards, until you no longer find it in search results. It would be very inefficient and expensive. Either way, you need to use a search endpoint, not a StreamListener, because the streaming API only fetches current realtime "new" Tweets, not old ones.